# Lexing error on line or parse error i am getting on 1st line,i want use multiple data in Example with combination Scenario Outline

Tags: selenium, cucumber-java

```
Feature:Login
Scenario Outline:validate uidfield
When:enter"<u>" userid
And click uid next
Then validate output for "<uc>" as userid criteria
When close site
Examples:
  bn      |    u            | uc
  chrome  |xxx.selenium   | valid 
  chrome  |xxx.selenium@7 | invalid 
  chrome  |                 |  blank
```

Answer (score 2):

The column names and the values should be wrapped with `|` in either examples table or in data table, as shown below.

```
Feature:Login
Scenario Outline:validate uidfield
When:enter"<u>" userid
And click uid next
Then validate output for "<uc>" as userid criteria
When close site
Examples:
  |bn      |    u            | uc     |
  |chrome  |xxx.selenium     | valid  |
  |chrome  |xxx.selenium@7   | invalid| 
  |chrome  |                 |  blank |
```